# Check e.KeyChar against an array of keys

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, key

Is this possible to check against?  I can't find much help on MSDN or anywhere for that matter.  Rather than having a multitude of if/elses to check for if numbers were entered into this textbox I have, I wanted to throw it all in an array or list and do a simple contain(which doesnt exist) against what was entered.  All I want it to do is remove the highlighted empty text in the textbox if any number is entered while inside the textbox.

```
 Private Sub txt_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles fptSSN.KeyPress
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim keysList As List(Of Keys)
        Dim keys() As Keys = {Windows.Forms.Keys.D0, Windows.Forms.Keys.D1, Windows.Forms.Keys.D2, Windows.Forms.Keys.D3, Windows.Forms.Keys.D4, Windows.Forms.Keys.D5, Windows.Forms.Keys.D6, Windows.Forms.Keys.D7, Windows.Forms.Keys.D8, Windows.Forms.Keys.D9, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad0, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad1, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad2, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad3, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad4, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad5, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad6, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad7, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad8, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad9}

        keysList.AddRange(keys)

           If txt.Text = "         " And e.KeyChar = ?????????????? Then
                txt.Text = ""
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're looking for numbers, you can leverage the IsNumeric() function:

```
    If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
        txt.Text = String.Empty
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

Set e.Handled = True if you don't want the number to be in the Textbox when you clear it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Private Sub txt_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) _
                        Handles fptSSN.KeyPress

    Dim keysList As New List(Of Keys)(New Keys() _
    {
        Windows.Forms.Keys.D0, Windows.Forms.Keys.D1, Windows.Forms.Keys.D2,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.D3, Windows.Forms.Keys.D4, Windows.Forms.Keys.D5,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.D6, Windows.Forms.Keys.D7, Windows.Forms.Keys.D8,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.D9, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad0,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad1, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad2,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad3, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad4,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad5, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad6,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad7, Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad8,
        Windows.Forms.Keys.NumPad9
    })

    If keysList.Any(Function(key) key.Equals(e.KeyChar)) AndAlso txt.Text = "         " Then
        txt.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  In the future should I have more keys to check other than numeric this would be a great function but in this case, since I'm only using numbers IsNumeric is the safe way to go. :) thanks!